# Clarification on how to use os.path.dirname with Django

Tags: python, django, dirname, os.path

I am using Django 1.5 and Python 2.7. My project directory is the usual:

There is the project folder called projectFolder. Inside projectFolder, there are two other folders: projFolder and projApp.

Inside projFolder is my settings.py, **init**.py and urls.py.

Inside projApp is my models.py, views.py and my static folder which holds my templates. Now, in my settings.py file, I have the following:

```
SITE_MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'projApp/', 'static/', 'site_media' 
)
```

The lines of code above work perfectly fine and this is what I read in the tutorial I was following. However, shouldn't it be

```
SITE_MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), '../', 'projApp/', 'static/', 'site_media' 
)
```

? From my understanding,

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

is the path to the directory which the current file is in, correct? So that would be projFolder since settings.py is in projFolder. So shouldn't I back out of the current directory first and then enter the projApp folder in order to get to the static folder? Doesn't the line

```
os.path.dirname(__file__), 'projApp/', 'static/', 'site_media'
```

mean that Django should search

```
projectFolder/projFolder/projApp/static
```

? If yes, then how is it finding static without backing out of the current settings.py directory first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should :) At leasts that's how my projects have it, except instead of `..` there is this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

I think it comes now in setings.py by default.

Are you 10000% sure that the settings.py is where  you say it is?

Maybe try adding some print statements to settings.py and run the test sever, to see real values of those paths

```
 print os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Comment: Hm okay.. now that I think of it, I don't think SITE_MEDIA_ROOT is even in Django documentation and I don't think I'm even using it in my app, I guess that is why it isn't giving any errors. I think the tutorial I was reading meant to write just MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: nevermind, in my urls.py, I do use SITE_MEDIA_ROOT, like so: "    url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    { 'document_root': settings.SITE_MEDIA_ROOT }),"

Comment: @user2719875 that should be `MEDIA_ROOT` and / or `STATIC_ROOT` just the same, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: hm okay thanks.. I just change my SITE_MEDIA_ROOT and added a '../' in the front and everything still works normally. I will leave it with the '../' now.